# ln -s reports that a procedure failed, but creates symlinks nonetheless

Tags: find, ln

I am in the parent directory and there are a number of files with .fastq, .fq, .fastq.gz and .fq.gz extensions in different subdirectories. I created a subdirectory named FASTQC and want to create symlinks to all of them in that subdirectory.

When I try:

```
find "$PWD" \( ! -path "$PWD/FASTQC" -type f -name *.f*q -o -name *.f*q.gz \) -exec ln -sv {} "$PWD/FASTQC" \;
```

I get symlinks to all my files in FASTQC, but also the following error messages:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/XXX/YYY/ZZZ/aaa.fastq.gz': File exists
```

When I execute the following two commands instead, I get all the symlinks created without any error messages.

```
find "$PWD" \( ! -path "$PWD/FASTQC" -type f -name *.f*q  \) -exec ln -sv {} "$PWD/FASTQC" \;
find "$PWD" \( ! -path "$PWD/FASTQC" -type f -name *.f*q.gz \) -exec ln -sv {} "$PWD/FASTQC" \;
```

Why do I get error messages with the first command?

EDIT: In case someone finds this question later through Google, here is the final working version (thank you, `ilkkachu` and `steeldriver`):

```
find "$PWD" ! -path "$PWD/FASTQC" -type f \( -name "*.f*q" -o -name "*.f*q.gz" \) \
    -exec ln -sv {} "$PWD/FASTQC" \;
```

Comment: You should quote patterns like `*.f*q.gz` (i.e. `'*.f*q.gz'` or `"*.f*q.gz"`) to make sure they are expanded by `find` rather than by the shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
( ! -path "..." -type f -name ... -o -name ...gz ) -exec ...
```

is parsed as

```
( ( ! -path "..." -type f -name ... ) -o ( -name ...gz ) ) -exec ...
```

because (the implied) *and* binds stronger than *or*. You probably want

```
! -path "..." -type f ( -name ... -o -name ...gz ) -exec
```

to have the `! -path` (and `-type`) filter apply to `*.gz` files too. The final `-exec` is also part of the implied *and* chain, so other than the pair with `-o` in between, the actions don't need parenthesis around them.

With your expression in full:

```
find "$PWD" ! -path "$PWD/FASTQC" -type f \( -name *.f*q -o -name *.f*q.gz \) \
    -exec ln -sv {} "$PWD/FASTQC" \;
```

Comment: Just tested - works like a charm, thank you!